# Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list) Spacy NLP

Tags: python, list, nlp

I want to calculate cosine similarity, but I got an error message after converting the dataframe column to its list: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list).

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

df= [['24, Single, Consultant, Canada, I am interested in visiting Isreal again'], ['18, Single, Student, I want to go back Costa Rica again'], ['45,Married, Unemployed, I want to take my family to Florida for the summer vacation']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Free Text'])
df["N_Application"]=range(0, len(df))

# convert datafram to list
data=df['Free Text'].tolist()
df_spacy=nlp(data)
```

I appreciate someone help me fix it, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you get a function to operate across an entire `pd.Series` is to use `.apply()`. And you can chain `.apply()` calls.

Example:

```
# changing to strings instead of nested list
l = ['24, Single, Consultant, Canada, I am interested in visiting Isreal again', 
     '18, Single, Student, I want to go back Costa Rica again', 
     '45,Married, Unemployed, I want to take my family to Florida for the summer vacation']

# remove stop words and punctuation for later similarity calculations
df_spacy = df['Free Text'].apply(nlp)\
                          .apply(lambda doc: nlp(' '.join(str(t) 
                                                 for t in doc 
                                                 if not t.is_stop 
                                                 and not t.is_punct)))
```

Edit: per your comment, here is a similarity calculation between each row and all other rows:

```
df_spacy.apply(lambda row: df_spacy\
        .apply(lambda doc: row.similarity(doc) if row != doc else None))
```

Resulting similarity matrix:

```
          0         1         2
0       NaN  0.776098  0.716560
1  0.776098       NaN  0.705024
2  0.716560  0.705024       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to get a list with three elements: ['24, Single, Consultant, Canada, I am interested in visiting Isreal again',
 '18, Single, Student, I want to go back Costa Rica again',
 '45,Married, Unemployed, I want to take my family to Florida for the summer vacation'], then I can apply similarity() to compare between three elements. Can I do it? Thank you

Comment: See updated answer. I believe you're wanting to apply the `similarity()` calculation for each row to all other rows.

Comment: Very nice. I have an extra question. If I have the second column, but I want to apply the same functions: 1) remove stopwords and punctuation, and 2) similarity for each column (comparing rows in its own column), then save them in the same place. Thank you

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't able to understand exactly what you're asking in this extra question.

Comment: No worries, it is better to open another forum for the discussion. Thank you. It works perfectly for me.